# Strange make implicit rule

Tags: makefile

I have written a small makefile for a few simple C programs that compiles them and then tests their execution time:

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -Wall
PTEST = /usr/bin/time -f "%Us"
ARCH=-march=native
OPTIMIZATION=
NOPTIMIZATION=

%comp : %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(NOPTIMIZATION) -o $* $<
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(OPTIMIZATION) -o $*_opt $<
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(NOPTIMIZATION) $(ARCH) -o $*_arch $<
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(OPTIMIZATION) $(ARCH) -o $*_opt_arch $<

%test:  
    @echo ---$<---  
    @echo Bez optymalizacji, bez podowania architektury
    @$(PTEST) ./$*
    @echo Bez optymalizacji, uwzgledniana architektura
    @$(PTEST) ./$*_arch
    @echo Opcja $(OPTIMIZATION), bez podawania architektury
    @$(PTEST) ./$*_opt
    @echo Opcja $(OPTIMIZATION), uwzgledniania architektura
    @$(PTEST) ./$*_opt_arch

loop%:OPTIMIZATION=-O2
logic%:OPTIMIZATION=-O1
math%:OPTIMIZATION=-O1 -ffast-math
recursive%:OPTIMIZATION=-O2 -foptimize-sibling-calls
recursive%:NOPTIMIZATION=-O2 -fno-optimize-sibling-calls

#all: loopcomp logiccomp mathcomp recursivecomp looptest logictest mathtest  recursivetest 

loop:loopcomp looptest

clean:
    rm -rf loop loop_opt loop_arch loop_opt_arch \
    logic logic_opt logic_arch logic_opt_arch \
    math math_opt math_arch math_opt_arch \
    recursive recursive_opt recursive_arch recursive_opt_arch
```

When I type make loop it compiles and tests them but then it invokes strange implicit rule that does this:

```
gcc -Wall    loop.c loopcomp looptest   -o loop
gcc: error: loopcomp: No such file or directory
gcc: error: looptest: No such file or directory
```

I know that this is make implicit rule because when I invoke `make -r loop` everything goes OK. I can't figure it out: which built-in implicit rule is make trying to invoke and how can I override it, preferably without adding `-r` option when invoking `make`?  If it is possible, I would like to override it or somehow diasable make implicit rules inside makefile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to create a file called "loop" and you just want to be able to say "make loop" as a way to bundle up other targets (like "make all") then you should declare "loop" to be phony and make won't search for implicit rules:

```
.PHONY: loop
loop: loopcomp looptest
```

If you don't want to do that but want to ensure that a given target doesn't undergo implicit rule search, then you should declare an explicit rule for it.  A simple way to do that is add a do-nothing recipe, like this:

```
loop: loopcomp looptest
        @:
```

(the ":" command is the shell's "do-nothing" command).

Answer (score 1):

Your default target in the makefile is:

```
loop:  loopcomp looptest
```

This tells `make` that to build `loop`, it must first ensure that `loopcomp` and `looptest` are up to date, and then it must find a way to build `loop`.  Since there is a file `loop.c`, it invokes its default `%.c:` rule to build `loop`:

```
gcc -Wall    loop.c loopcomp looptest   -o loop
```

This includes the two files (programs) you told it that `loop` depends on.

While you have a `loop.c`, I think you're likely to run into this problem.

There does not seem to be a way to say in the `makefile` "do not use any built-in rules".  If there was, you'd expect it to be a 'Special Built-in Target Name' (§4.8 of the GNU Make manual for version 3.82), such as `.DEFAULT`.

Your only remaining hope is that declaring `.PHONY: loop` might suppress this.  Otherwise, rewrite the default target rule as:

```
check-loop: loopcomp looptest
```

---

This is a mind-boggling `makefile`.  Porting that to anything other than GNU `make` will not be trivial.

Comment: I don't intent, this is small assigment for which I tried to write short make-file, thanks for an advice on .PHONY, it worked.